# Delphi add/remove fields at runtime

Tags: sql, delphi, components

I need to add into my Delphi application a functionality that will allow the user to add/remove fields in a database table (SQL server 2008) such that the fields will be automatically created/removed on/from the form.

e.g.

The user right-clicks on form and a popup menu like:

> 'Add field --> Field Name --> Field type --> Allow Null --> etc'

appears. After the user has chosen all the variables, the field is added to the table AND the form. I've seen a similar functionality in various projects.

Is there a component/library for such a function? I googled it but I didn't find anything similar. Any suggestion?

Comment: Very unlikely, because that component/library would have to know what your form looks like. Please explain how you access your SQL server table (what Delphi components), and what components should be added to your form (corresponding with the added field) so that people can give you specific help. Adding some existing code may help too.

Comment: thank you for your answer @Jan. I am using a custom form (that inherits from TForm) which is linked to a custom module (that inherits from TDataModule). To simplify things, lets say I access my SQL Serve table through a Tquery. A datasource is linked to the Tquery and all the TDBEdit components on my form are linked to the datasource. The only components I want the user to add are TDBEdits (with fields that somehow will be created in the database table). I hope I made sense, please notify me if more details are needed, thank you!

Comment: What you are wanting to do can be done by: Closing the TQuery then doing an Alter Table to add the column, then open the TQuery again, create the TDBEdit and link it to the TDataSource and Field you just created.  But you will then need to create all the TDBEdits on the fly every time the screen is created or the TQuery is opened.

Comment: @TDC I think I can manage that with Devexpress Layout control, I can also save and load the new form with this tool. At least I hope so :P. Thank you for your reply!